# How can I configuring php.ini in the homestead laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead, laravel-5.6

When I run my script, there exist error like this :

```
 maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

So I need to edit in the php.ini. But here I using laravel homestead

I'm confused to change it in laravel homestead

I had get some reference. But i'm still confused to implement it

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should use Vagrant to change php execution time

Answer (score 4):

If you need this for testing purposes, you can edit that in runtime with :

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo find / -name php.ini` to locate your php.ini file.

You script lasts more than 30s, if your are not running a time cost jobs, there may be something wrong with your code.

Comment: I had run it. But then how can I set maximum execution time? Can you update your answer with a detail answer

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `.user.ini` file into the in **public/** directory with the settings and values of your choice like this (60 seconds in this case):

```
[PHP]
max_execution_time = 60
```

You can read more about this in the [PHP .user.ini files official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)